# How does Maven resolve dependencies in a multi-module Maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that consists of two modules: API and IMPL. Below is the content of IMPL's pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>API</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run the command `mvn clean compile` in the root directory, it works fine, which confuses me. I **do not** have an artifact named API in my local repository. So how does Maven find the API artifact?

When using JetBrains IDE, it gets even more weird. Once I write any class in the API module, I can use them directly in the IMPL module without needing to run the `mvn compile` or `mvn install` command.

I would like to know how Maven finds the API artifact and how JetBrains IDE locates the API module. Could you please explain the mechanisms behind them? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maven has something called the [reactor (`maven.apache.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). All modules in a multii-module build are executed in the same reactor; all artifacts of a build-step will be available in subsequent steps of the reactor. Maven figures out the order in which the modules must be built automatically. Try running the build on the submodule that uses the `API` artifact, you'll see that this build will fail (when `API` is not in your local repository), and maven will tell you that it cannot resolve the `API` artifact.

Comment: @Turing85 It is even more sophisticated because a command like `mvn clean compile` does not create artifacts at all, but nevertheless "resolves" dependencies within the reactor.

Comment: Have you ever executed mvn clean install from the root module? My educated guess is that you have done that at least once? Check your local cache (`$HOME/.m2/repository/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/...` )

Comment: @khmarbaise No, this is a brand new Maven project, I never run the command `mvn clean install`. Also, I have checked my Maven repo, and no artifact has group id 'org.example'

Comment: @Turing85 So, IDEA has a real-time reactor？

Comment: I am not sure how what IntelliJ is doing. I would imagine that intelliJ analyzes the dependency structure (i.e. looks at the `pom.xml` files) to "know" what (sub-)projects are used for features like auto-completion.